# open graph - the action type must either be approved for user-generated photos

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have recently updated our open graph action to include user-generated photos but are recieving the following error. Our action is already approved so not sure what is going on?

(#100) The action type (155314644560172) must either be approved for user-generated photos or the action must be taken by an app developer.

[image: the action is approved already]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

User Generated photos requires additional approval before you can use it. When submitting your action for approval in the DevApp, be sure to check the box, "User Generated Photos".
[image]

Comment: My mistake, the error message changed causing me to believe that our app had been approved for user-generated photos. It's such an annoyance that we have to delete the action and re-submit it just to use user-generated photos!!

Comment: I agree, but the extra step helps prevent the whole open system from getting bogged with spam.